# rails and html, how to retrieve params from a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

i have the follow

```
<%= form_tag lessons_path, :method => 'get', :name => "filter_form" do %>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="is_private" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
  <button value="0" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Public</button>
  <button value="1" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Private</button>
</div>
```

when a user clicks on either of those buttons, the form submits and goes to my lessons#index. how can i get what value the user clicked on? i understand that params[:something] usually comes from a GET request in the url, but what about in this case?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give your buttons `name` attributes:

```
<%= form_tag lessons_path, :method => 'get', :name => "filter_form" do %>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="is_private" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
    <button name="public"  type="submit" value="0" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Public</button>
    <button name="private" type="submit" value="1" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Private</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and then check `params` as usual in your controller:

```
if(params[:public])
    # public has pressed
elsif(params[:private])
    # private was pressed
else
    # Hmm, someone is trying to cause trouble.
end
```

You'll note that I added `type="submit"` to the `<button>`s, some browsers use `type="submit"` as the default (as per [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)) and some use `type="button"` so it is best to be explicit.

Comment: so if things normally have a name attribute, they can be checked in the params?

Comment: @Crystal: Yes, the `name` attribute exists specifically to get things to the server in a predictable way.

Answer (score 1):

In rails, the params hash will contain all the elements that have been submitted/passed to the page.  This includes GET parameters and POST parameters.  You should be using a [check box](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) (or perhaps radio buttons) to represent this type of data.  If your field exists on the database, then you should do the following:

```
<br><%= f.check_box :is_private %> Private
```

You can then access the data with `params[:is_private]`

If you want to use buttons, then I Would recommend creating two urls to toggle the state of the check box.  Otherwise you will have to depend on JavaScript to change a field.

If you want to use buttons, but also use the same update url, then you will need to have the button presses toggle the state of the check box there are JQuery plugins that can do this (one example is http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/).

Answer (score 1):

A form will only submit to one action.

Use i18n to define your button text then check the i18n value of value of the commit param in the controller action

e.g.
in your form

```
<%= submit_tag I18n.t('checkout.button.place_order'), :class => "submit" %>
```

The same will work for a f.submit button.

then in your controller

```
if params[:commit] == I18n.t('checkout.button.place_order')
  Do something
else
  Do something else
end
```

The in your en.yml or whatever to define the actual text

```
en:
  checkout:
    button:
      place_order: 'Place Order'
```

Obviously just adjust to suit your needs

By using i18n, you can easily change the text on your buttons in the i18n definition without having any effect on your controller logic and will still work on any internationalisation/translations you wish to use

Using this you can set up as many buttons on a single form as you like then add whatever conditional logic you need in the controllers action

**UPDATE**
I18n is short for internationalisation (18 chars in the word :)), just create a file in the locale folder called en.yml then define whatever you need in the format that I described above and you are good to go.
Reference I18n variables anywhere you need them using the t. helper
Have a look at this railscast for more detailed explanation
http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n

**Update 2** In response to mu is too short's comment below

> Why not just add a name attribute? Then you can work with what the
>   button independent of its content. Keep in mind that a  can
>   contain embedded HTML that won't make much sense inside param

using i18n makes this comment totally invalid as the text is not checked at all. You can make the text whatever you want and indeed it is good practice to use I18n. Note that you are checking the constant in the controller 'checkout.button.place_order' in the above example NOT the value which is defined as 'Place Order'.

Comment: thanks for answering though i wasnt quite looking for the i18n. i have no idea what that is actually but thank you nonetheless = )

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly, give it a go, you'll learn something new :)

Comment: Why not just add a `name` attribute? Then you can work with what the button independent of its content. Keep in mind that a `<button>` can contain embedded HTML that won't make much sense inside `params`.

Comment: @mu is too short - I think you missed the point! Using i18n makes the text on the button totally irrelevant! Read my answer again and try understand it better :)

Comment: I know what you're doing but you'll have problems if you don't use `name`. What would you do with `<button type="submit"><img src="..."><br>Pancakes</button>`? What do you expect that to send to the server? What do you think `<button type="submit">Pancakes</button>` is going to send to the server when you click it? How about `<input type="submit" value="Pancakes">`? A form control without a `name` is pretty much useless from the server's point of view.

Comment: My solution really doesn't care at all what the content is so long as you use i18n. How on earth would you translate you example into multiple language. My solution is dead simple and it handles all scenarios equally well and is just as valid as providing a name. It's a solution I have used many times with no problems at all

Comment: Sorry, you're still completely missing the point. I18N has nothing at all to do with this, neither does `submit_tag` as that doesn't produce a `<button>` (and so `params[:commit]` won't work). You're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: submit_tag DOES produce a button but my reply also mentions f.button as well. and it totally does provide the solution. You should try it. Please feel free to invite me into a chat room to discuss