# Rails: Get checked radio-button value with html input tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, radio-button, simple-form

I have a simple structure of contest:

- The contest has multiple questions
- Each question has multiple answers
  possible

For this I feel like what I've created is a good structure:
[image]

I am trying to get the answers of a user for each question from the form in my view to my controller. Long story short, I was **unable to use** the `<%= collection_radio_buttons ... %>` because the method wouldn't be right. There is not one column in my model for each answer to each question. answer_option is not a column in my questions table it's an association because it's another table... (or would you know how to help on that?)

So I've bypassed this issue by creating loops on answers_options of each question and using html inputs and labels, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @contest, url: contest_send_quizz_path(@contest), method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| %>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
      <h4 class="mt-5"><%= question.title %></h4>
      <% question.answer_options.each do |answer_option| %>
        <div class="inputGroup">
          <input type="radio" name=<%= answer_option.question_id %> value="<%= answer_option.answer %>" id=<%= answer_option.id %> />
          <label for=<%= answer_option.id %>><%= answer_option.answer %></label>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="mt-3">
    <span class="button-effect-2">
        <%= f.button :button, "Envoyer", type: :submit, class:"text-white" %>
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However now the problem is fetching those values in the controller. It seems with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309664/rails-and-html-how-to-retrieve-params-from-a-form) that I'd have to get it with `params[:something]` and that `:something` being the name of the input. Is that right? And now that I know that, does putting `params[:name]` (which is the same for all concerned radio buttons of one question) directly get the checked radio, or is there another thing to do?

Here is what I have for now, there is stuff to ignore since the structure of the rest of my code is bigger than just the contest. This is in the `ContestsController`:

```
def show
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:id])
    authorize @contest
    @time_left = seconds_to_units(@contest.deadline - Time.now)
    @is_done =  @contest.deadline < Time.now
    if @is_done
      get_winner
    end
    @questions = @contest.questions.includes([:answer_options])
end

def send_quizz
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
    @questions = @contest.questions.includes([:answer_options])
    authorize @contest
    current_user.contests << @contest
    user_choice = # TODO : Get checked radio value from view
    user_contest = current_user.contests.select { |contest| contest.title == @contest.title }.first
    user_contest.questions.each do |question|
      question.user_answer = user_choice
    end
    # TODO : make sure every questions were answered before submitting request
    redirect_to contests_path
    flash[:notice] = "Ta réponse a été prise en compte"
end
```

So is there a way to get this value, or should I change my db structure so that each question has one column for each answer? Or maybe another solution? Thanks !

---

**EDIT:**

I also tried replacing this:

```
<input type="radio" name="<%= answer_option.question_id %>" value="<%= answer_option.answer %>" id="<%= answer_option.id %>" />
<label for="<%= answer_option.id %>"><%= answer_option.answer %></label>
```

With this:

```
<%= q.check_box :answer_option, name:answer_option.question_id, id:answer_option.id %>
<%= q.label :answer_option, answer_option.answer, for:answer_option.id %>
```

And getting the value in the controller with `user_choice = params[:answer_option]` but when I replaced `check_box` with `radio_button`, it messed up the name, id etc. values AND I couldn't select anymore.

---

**EDIT 2:**

By adding this structure:

```
<%= q.radio_button :answer_option, answer_option.answer %>
<%= q.label :answer_option, answer_option.answer %>
```

It works (no errors), however the name is set automatically and to something not specific to each question i.e. `contest[questions][answer_option]` and the label's for is set to `contest_questions_answer_option`, therefore clicking on the label does not link to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to retrieve the value of the checkbox with this structure for the radio-buttons:

```
<%= q.radio_button answer_option.question_id, answer_option.answer %>
<%= q.label "#{answer_option.question_id}_#{answer_option.answer.parameterize.underscore}", answer_option.answer %>
```

And the controller:

```
user_choices = params[:contest][:questions]
user_contest.questions.each do |question|
  question[:user_answer] = "#{user_choices[:'#{question.id}']}"
  question.save
end
```